# Why the SSMS-setup-ENU for version 17.8.1 isn't running?

Tags: ssms

I have successfully downloaded and installed the developer version of SQL server 2017. Then I went to the SSMS website and downloaded the latest version of SSMS, which is 17.8.1. The exe file was properly downloaded and it is not damaged at all. When I double-clicked it, windows ask me if I am allowing this app to change my device. I clicked yes. Then nothing happened. The installation process just won't begin. My system is 64bit win10, and it is updated to the latest version. I have also downloaded some earlier versions of SSMS such as 17.5 and 17.3 and I encountered the exact same problem. I'd like to know if it has anything to do with my visual studio? I have downloaded and installed the latest visual studio 2017, and it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the latest dot net framework is not installed. The setup does not show what is its missing it just do not run.

You can try installing 4.6.2 net
Go to this link. 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53344

After finishing installation.

Run SSMS setup and it will show the installation screen.