# SQL Server Management Studio set-up exe does not launch

Tags: windows, installation, ssms

Attempting to launch the SQL Server Management Studio set-up exe leads to an icon briefly appearing in the taskbar, before disappearing without any further screen showing up. The task manager does not show any running instance for the installer either.

I have tried various versions of the SSMS installer executables posted on [Microsoft's official documentation for SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017#previous-versions), including version 18.8, 18.7.1, and 17.9.1.

Also tried updating the .NET framework, as suggested here ([Why the SSMS-setup-ENU for version 17.8.1 isn't running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51321682/why-the-ssms-setup-enu-for-version-17-8-1-isnt-running)), but the latest version is already showed as having been installed.

I did a soft and hard reboot both, without success.

Confused as to how to proceed and install the software now. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A few things to try... 1. Try right-clicking and selecting "Run as Administrator." 2. Try running it from a Command Prompt window in case it outputs error messages to STDOUT/STDERR. 3. Try disabling antivirus software or adding the setup executable to its "Allow" list.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thanks, but I forgot to mention in the post - I did try the first 2 things. No further sign of the actual issue popped up. In the case of the cmd window, it just launched the executable similarly, with the icon of SSMS set-up appearing in the taskbar and then disappearing in a second, with the execution returning to a new line in the cmd. And I only have Microsoft Defender, so anti-virus shouldn't be the issue :(

Comment: did you manage t solve it?

Comment: Hi @user384496, unfortunately not. I think I switched to Azure Data Studio.